# Where is the buildObject() method of the Shadowbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, shadowbox

Where is the buildObject() method of the Shadowbox?

http://www.shadowbox-js.com/api.html

The api says there is a buildObject() but it's missing from my download.

I downloaded it from the below link with the JQuery adapter and selected the first 3 check boxes:

http://www.shadowbox-js.com/download.html

Has anyone had any luck with this?

Thanks,

Comment: I think there is a typo in the documentation or that is an older or possibly newer documentation set. I would contact the author regarding that.

Comment: Unable to find anything in the source: https://github.com/mjijackson/shadowbox

Answer (score 0):

I achieved what I needed without the buildObject method:

```
function ShowLoginPage() {

    Shadowbox.open({
        content: "Login.aspx",
        player: "iframe",
        type: "iframe",         
        height: 175,
        width: 301,
        options: {
            onOpen: login_shadowboxOpen,
            onFinish: login_shadowboxFinish,
            onClose: login_shadowboxClose,
            modal: true
        }
    });
}
```